# Velocity.js: Animate second set of objects after first set finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg, velocity.js

I'm trying to animate a series of SVG objects. Here's the basic goal: The first set of 4 objects animates in, then out, and then the next set of objects animate in. While the first 2 queue up just fine, I'm not sure of the best method to get the second set to wait until the first set finishes.

Here's my code:

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.dt0,.dt1,.dt2,.dt3').velocity("transition.perspectiveRightIn", {stagger: 200, drag: true });
        $('.dt0,.dt1,.dt2,.dt3').velocity("transition.perspectiveRightOut", {stagger: 200, drag: true });
        $('.tr0,.tr1,.tr2,.tr3').velocity("transition.perspectiveRightIn", {stagger: 200, drag: true });
        })
```

UPDATE: Here's my solution, but I'm bothered by utilizing a delay rather than a queuing method.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.dt0,.dt1,.dt2,.dt3').velocity("transition.expandIn", {stagger: 200, drag: true });
        $('.dt0,.dt1,.dt2,.dt3').velocity("transition.expandOut", {stagger: 200, drag: true, delay: 1000 });
        $('.tr0,.tr1,.tr2,.tr3').velocity({opacity: 0}, {duration:0 });
        $('.tr0,.tr1,.tr2,.tr3').velocity("transition.expandIn", {stagger: 200, drag: true, delay: 3000 });
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the callbacks?

```
$('.dt0').velocity({
  opacity: 0 //or animation name
 }, {
 complete: function(elements) { 
  $('.dt1').velocity({
    opacity: 0 //or animation name
   }, {
   complete: function(elements) { 
    //... the others
   },{duration:200, delay:2000 } //2s delay
   });
 },{duration:1000 }
});
```